# Foundation 6, reInit slider plugin with new settings / options

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

How can i change a plugin's settings/options dynamically. In this case slider plugin. I am trying to change *data-step*.

**Here what i tried:**

```
function changeDataStep($val) {
           var slider = new Foundation.Slider( $('#slider') );
           $('#slider').foundation('destroy');
           slider = new Foundation.Slider( $('#slider'), { dataStep: $val } );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes which starts with **data** in javascript is the source of confusion.

**Correct Way is:**

```
function changeDataStep($val) {
           var slider = new Foundation.Slider( $('#slider') );
           slider = new Foundation.Slider( $('#slider'), { step: $val } );
}
```